# How to make a new line with a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want the new number to get a new line without removing the old number ?

See the picture

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGJKP.gif]

Comment: Not clear what you want. Does the image display what you are aiming for or what you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 if let exitingText = label.text
 {
    label.text = exitingText + "\n" + (textField.text ?? "")

 }
```

and set

```
label.numberOflines = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use on click of button

```
- (IBAction)btnAppendTextClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSString *oldText=_lblWithText.text;
    _lblWithText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",oldText,_txtValues.text];
    _lblWithText.numberOfLines=0;
    _lblWithText.preferredMaxLayoutWidth =self.view.frame.size.width;
    [_lblWithText setNeedsDisplay];
}
```